# VSTS Magic Chunks config transfomer alternative for Mac build

Tags: c#, xamarin, io, azure-devops

I am using Magic Chunks(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks) to replace appsettings.json file based on environment build in my VSTS build.

This works on windows build agent machine for android, but crashes on mac build agent machine, due to not supported:
https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/magic-chunks/issues/43

Basically what plugin does it allows to replace appsettings.json values before build task happens in vsts build:
[image]

Is there any working alternative for Mac?

I tried token replacement from here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens which is easy if you use place holders to replace, but I don't use placeholders, since appsettings.json already has legit values for parameters.

My other option is to create old school appsettings.{build}.json now but I kind of don't want that.. But I would rather stay with one file only.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using powershell script. After adding PS task into build I've chosen inline script:

```
$a = Get-Content -Path appsettings.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$a.AppSettings.ApiUrl = "$(ApiUrl)"
$a | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path appsettings.json
```

Comment: Can you include the detail script to the answer?